# Proving a set is algebraic.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, zariski-topology

I want to investigate about if the set of points of the form $(x,1)$ with $x\neq 0$ (horizontal line without a point) is closed or not in $\mathbb{A}_k^n$ with the zariski topology.

My intuition say me yes. I think that the smaller algebraic set containg this set of points is $V(y-1)$, which consist of the entire horizontal line. However, I do not have idea about how I can avance...

Comment: Have you tried drawing this set?

Comment: @Daniel yes, this set is a horizontal line without a point... A suppose I suppose that the smaller algebraic set containg this set of points is $V(y-1)$ which consist of the entire line...

Comment: Right, so what would its closure be?

Comment: @Daniel if the set is not closed, this would be $V(y-1)$ and if this set is closed, its closure would be the same set...

Comment: Right. Now show that the closure of your set is $V(y - 1).$ Hint: The set is open in $V(y - 1)$, which is irreducible.

Comment: @Daniel I think that I get it! It is very clear that the set is open in that line because points are closed. Then, because open sets are dense in the affine space, and because my horizontal line is the affine line, then I can conclude that the closure of my set must be the entire line... What do you think about it?...

Comment: Yes, that seems right to me. Nice job!

Comment: @Daniel thank you so much!... Can You write some answer for give you the points?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139631/discussion-between-3435-and-daniel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two constraints: one which is closed and one which is open.

First, you constrain $y = 1$, which is a zariski closed condition, since this is the same as saying $y - 1 = 0$. Then, you constrain $x \neq 0$, which is a zariski open condition.

As such, your set will be an open subset of a closed subset in $\mathbb{A}^2$. These are typically not open or closed in $\mathbb{A}^2$.